# Laravel Blade @foreach not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm learning Laravel 4, so far so good. But for some weird reason blade's @foreach doesn't seem to work for a simple query. My code is:

Route:

```
Route::get('/users', function(){

    $users = User::all();

    return View::make('users/index')->with('users',$users);

});
```

Now in index.blade.php my code is:

```
  @foreach ($users as $user)

        <p>User: {{ $user->username }}</p>

  @endforeach
```

The weird thing is that when I dump the object in the view, it does work:

```
{{ dd($users->toArray())}}
```

The DB data is displayed raw as an array.

I'm not really sure what am I doing wrong here, this is pretty much code from the beginners tutorial.

Comment: What is the error/problem you get with the foreach loop?

Comment: nothing is being displayed, no error log either.

Comment: Make sure you have used the `index.blade.php` as the name of the `view` file, I doubt you missed the `blade` it.

Comment: what if you replace `View::make('users/index')` by `View::make('users.index')`

Comment: Double checked the view name on finder: index.blade.php  and adding the dot instead of / doesn't seem to change the result

Comment: Do you have a `username` field, did you try other fields ?

Comment: The `username` field could be empty in `$user/User` model, check other fields/properties.

Comment: Yeah, tried with password, id and username :/

Comment: I mean is probably to much to ask but you can see the whole /app folder at github.   https://github.com/OmarGRocha/laratest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `template/layout` (but you didn't use according to your [view on Github](https://github.com/OmarGRocha/laratest/blob/master/views/users/index.blade.php)) and child views should extend it, for example, your `index.blade.php` view should be look something like this:

```
// index.blade.php
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <p>User: {{ $user->username }}</p>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Now make sure that, in your `app/views/layouts` folder you have a `master.blade.php` layout and it contains something like this:

```
// master.blade.php
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='content'>
            @yield('content') {{-- This will show the rendered view data --}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also `dd($users->toArray())` works because it dumps the `$user->toArray()` using `var_dump` and exits the script using `die` function, the `dd` means `dump and die`.

Comment: yeah its a bit confusing the tutorial haven't mention master views at all, the framework seems awesome thou.

Comment: Yes it's nice, I love it. You may also [like these articles](http://heera.it/tag/laravel-2) and check the `view composer` and other articles as well, could be helpful for you (Laravel related).