# Cannot loop through Eloquent object in Blade using @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have looked at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225344/laravel-blade-foreach-not-working) but unfortunately the answer does not apply to me.

I know that my object does contain my data but the inside of the @foreach is never called in my view.

Here is my controller:

```
$newest_article = $this->article->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

$articles = Article::allButFirst($newest_article->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

return View::make('site/news/index', compact('newest_article', 'articles'));
```

My model's scopeAllButFirst function:

```
public function scopeAllButFirst($query, $id){
    return $query->where('id', '<>', $id);
}
```

And lastly my view:

```
@extends('site.layouts.default')

@section('content')
<section id="news-main">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- all posts wrapper -->
        <div class="news-box-wrap js-packery clearfix"  data-packery-options='{ "itemSelector": ".news-item"}'>

            @foreach($articles as $article)

                <div class="col-sm-4 news-item">
                    <a href="{{{ $article->url() }}}" class="news-box-inner">
                        <div class="news-box-image-wrap">
                            @if($article->image->url('tile_landscape'))
                                <img src="{{{ $article->image->url('tile_landscape') }}}" class="news-box-image">
                            @endif
                            <span class="news-box-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-box-bottom">
                            <div class="news-box-data">
                                <span class="news-box-cat">News</span>
                                &#8226;
                                <span class="news-box-time">{{{ $article->date() }}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <h3>{{{ $article->title }}}</h3>
                            <div class="news-box-det">
                                <span class="news-box-author">{{{ $article->author->username }}}</span>
                                <span class="news-box-like"><i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-lg"></i> 225</span>
                                <span class="news-box-comment"><i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-lg"></i> 16</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </a>
                </div>

            @endforeach
       </div>
@stop
```

I need to loop through the Eloquent object because I have to access some of the methods in my model class.

just as a reference, I am following [andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site)

**UPDATE**

In my debugging I noticed if I replace

```
$articles = Article::allButFirst($newest_article->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
```

with

```
$articles = Article::all();
```

I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing the problem, the answer as usual is in the API. Turns out you have to call the get() method in order to receive a Collection. And that is what all() returns. So simply changing

```
$articles = Article::allButFirst($newest_article->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
```

to

```
$articles = Article::allButFirst($newest_article->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

solves the problem.

Hope it helps